# Background color of Text-box

Tags: javascript, html, css, forms

I want the background color in the text-box to stay for at least 5 seconds after i click the submit button

but it is disappearing as soon as i click submit button.

This is my code...

```
<!DOCTYPE>
<html>
<head>
<title>Text Boxes With Aplhabets </title>
</head>
<body>`enter code here`

<script type="text/javascript">

 frm.alphabets.value="";
function AllowAlphabets(){
               if (!frm.alphabets.value.match(/^[a-zA-Z]+$/) )
               {

                    frm.alphabets.focus(); 
                    frm.alphabets.style.background="Red";
                    //alert("Please Enter only alphabets");
               }

}      
</script>

<form name="frm"   onsubmit="return AllowAlphabets()">
Enter Aplhabets: <input type="text" name="alphabets" />
<input type = "submit" value = "Submit">
</form>
<br;>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I think you want something like this http://jsfiddle.net/G6wa9/1/

Comment: Its not giving the expected results when u comment the alert box statement

Comment: so that's why I said ***I think***, in fact I don't white understand the behavior you want, just set the background to red without any info on the error will confuse user, we need a tooltip at least in this case.

Comment: The background color of the text-box will change if i enter anything other then aplhabets and click submit button but the background color will go off in a flash. I need the background to stay for some amount of time

Answer (score 1):

use `setTimeout()`

example :

```
setTimeout(myFunction, 2000);
```

or

```
setTimeout(function () {

//code here
}, 2000);
```

reference : [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/window.setTimeout)

Comment: The point is not just `setTimeout()`, the OP's code has some (not just 1) things wrong here. First the way to test the valid string is wrong, we have to use the `test()` method of RegExp object (not the match()  method of string object), secondly we have to `return false` or `e.preventDefault()` to cancel the `onsubmit`.

Comment: @KingKing But why don't you tell the OP that instead of commenting on an answer? You should also mention that the DOCTYPE is bad.